# MVC Generated SQL Query deletes key on Add

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

(This app is written in EF 4.4.0.0.  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] is in EF6 and above only.  Already tried to upgrade, and it caused WAY more problems.)

I have two, two column tables I update from my application.

One is `tblLanguages`, with a two letter abbreviation column, and the Language name column.  Unique key constraints keep the data clean.

The second, is a private school table (tblPrivateSchool), with an integer for a key, and a descriptor for the name of the school.  The key is a manual entry.

`tblLanguages` ADD works, `tblPrivateSchools` ADD does not.

```
     using (var db = new SIS_DBContext())
     {
        try
        {
           db.LanguageCode.Add(languageCode);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return true;
        }
        etc...
```

I use the exact same approach to the other two column table, and find MVC has stripped the key from the generated query, like it expects it to be an auto-generated Identity field.

```
     using (var db = new SIS_DBContext())
     {
        try
        {
           db.PrivateSchoolCodes.Add(privateSchoolCode);
           db.Entry(privateSchoolCode).State = EntityState.Added;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return true;
        }
```

I've tried dropping and recreating the table slightly differently, but no matter what, it seems MVC thinks the DB will supply the ID, and sends the query without the ID I've keyed in the app.

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[syn_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]([name])
values (@0)
select [code]
from [dbo].[syn_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [code] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(200)',@0=N'Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

I'm about to the point of adding an unneeded ID column to the table just to get around this.

Per your request:

```
public class PrivateSchoolCodes
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public Int16 code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "School Name cannot exceed 200 characters.")]
    public string name { get; set; }

public class LanguageCode
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Code must be two characters.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Language { get; set; }
```

So both are denoted as a key, and required, but I don't tell MVC that it is an autogenerated identity field.

Comment: What is definition of `PrivateSchoolCodes`? , seems it defined column code as Identity in EntityFramework

Comment: Updated per your request.